# How many bytes does an empty queue take?

Tags: c++, memory, queue

How many bytes does an empty queue, an empty vector, etc. take?

Comment: Depends on the implementation.

Comment: It's implementation defined.

Comment: And depends on processor architecture.

Comment: use `sizeof` to find out.

Comment: @NikBougalis: I don't think it's officially even ID (that would require that the implementation document it). More likely unspecified.

Comment: And @JerryCoffin scores. It's a semantics touchdown ;) But you are, of course, correct.

Comment: As many as it wants.  And doing `sizeof` will not produce the correct result if it contains internal heap allocations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is an implementation detail - the standard doesn't say much about it. We can probably figure out a minimum:

A `vector` would have (at least) a pointer to the data itself, an actual size and a capacity. So at least 3 times the size of an integer. Obviously, the size and pointer may be 64-bits, in which case it's 3 times 64-bits = 24 bytes. But there is no saying whether the size is or isn't 64-bit without looking at the actual implementation.

A `queue` is probably similar.

You can of course do `sizeof(vector<int>)` and see for yourself. But it's not guaranteed to be the same on a different architecture.

Comment: Consider, that the same reasoning should hold for `std::string`: it certainly has the data itself, a size and a capacity. Yet with g++ 4.7.2 in Windows, a `std::string` is 4 bytes, the size of a single pointer. Since the pointer it holds is non-zero the storage it uses is probably actually more than your minimum, but the point is that for an empty string that internal pointer *could* be a nullpointer, in which case the instance would only use space of a single pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to this question. This is entirely dependent on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a common implementation would be based on array or linked list. In that case it would need a pointer to the beginning of the queue and the length (or pointer to the end).  Which in turn means it would take sizeof(void*)*2 bytes. On x86_64 it would be equal to 16 bytes. A linked list would have two pointers as well. But different implementations may take more or less. For instance, one could use 24-bit base address and 8 bit to store the size, leading to only using 4 bytes for bookkeeping.